# Javascript Array Creation Using A Web Html Form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form like below
I need to create an array for each radio button using JavaScript and I need to post to a PHP script using Ajax

```
<form id="what" name="what" >
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" value="red" />Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" value="blue" />Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="green" value="green" />Green

<input type="radio" name="animals" id="dog" value="dog" />Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="animals" id="parrot" value="parrot" />Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="animals" id="horse" value="horse" />Green

<button type="button" >send</button>
</form>
```

My Ajax Posting Code

```
var data = 'username=' + username + '&api_password=' + apipassword + '&sender=' + sender + '&to=' + owner + "," +  mobile + '&message='  + "Name : " + name +"%0d%0a"+ "Mobile No : " + mobile +"%0d%0a"+ "Address : " + street +" "+ area + " " + formlandmark +"%0d%0a"+ "Notes : " + notes + "%0d%0a" + "Order Id : " + randomnewnewnumber + "%0d%0a" +  itemstosmsdata() + '&priority=' + priority;
var adminsubmit = 'name=' + name+'&mobile='+ mobile +'&adds='+ street +" "+ area + " " + formlandmark +'&notes='+ notes+'&orderid='+ randomnewnewnumber+'&orders='+ itemstowebdata()+'&status=opened'+'&time='+time+'&date='+ dates;
            $('.text').attr('disabled','true');
            $('.loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://something.some.com/appost.php?",   // Your Sms Api Url
                type: "POST",
                data: data,     
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {  
                    alert("Order Placed");  
                    if (html==1) {      

                        $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 
                        $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
                    }           
                }       
            });
```

The Data Sould Be Sent Like Below

```
  radio[ { "radiobuttonename" => clicked value of the radio button},{ "radiobuttonename" => clicked value of the radio button}]
```

Comment: hmm i dont no more abt ajax and jquery so i have not tried but i am know abt php

Comment: send us the format of data that you want to send using ajax.

Comment: @LukeAdamczewski Check My Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is to fill your array with all radio values within the form:

```
var theArray = []
$("#what > input[type='radio']").each(function(){
theArray.push($(this).val())
})

// theArray  will be like this: red,blue,green,dog,parrot,horse
```

If you want to pass the checked attribute with the array, you can do this:

```
theArray.push($(this).val() + "@" + this.checked)

// theArray  will be like this: red@false,blue@false,green@false,dog@true,parrot@false,horse@false
```

Finally, convert your array to string:

```
theArray = theArray.join("##")
```

and now you can send your array with ajax

Comment: hi i need only the checked value to be sent not all the values

Comment: then write: if(this.checked == true)theArray.push($(this).val())

Comment: not working check this  http://jsfiddle.net/PRmCg/1/

Comment: there are 2 syntax errors in your fiddle code, replace the loop:  $("#what > input[type='radio']").each(function(){
    if(this.checked == true){alert($(this).val())};
})

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following code (Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/))

**HTML**

```
<form id="what" name="what" >
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" value="red" />Red<br />
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" value="blue" />Blue<br />
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="green" value="green" />Green<br /><br />

    <input type="radio" name="animals" id="dog" value="dog" />Red<br />
    <input type="radio" name="animals" id="parrot" value="parrot" />Blue<br />
    <input type="radio" name="animals" id="horse" value="horse" />Green

    <input type="submit" value="send" name="btn" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('form#what').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm=$(this);
        var len=$('input:radio[name="colors"]:checked', frm).length;
        if(!len) 
        {
            alert('Please select a color');
            return false;
        }
        var arr=frm.serialize();
        $.post('ajax_php.php', arr,  function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            // do something with data 
        });
    });
});
```

You can receive the `colors` and `animals` variable in `php` as follows

```
$color=$_POST['colors'];
$animal=$_POST['animals'];
```

Comment: the user did not mention anything about jQuery

Comment: i have different types of radio button with different name and values with some different type of radio group for eg kinly check my question once sir i have updated

Answer (score 0):

This is a skeleton that should help you with serializing this form and send data using ajax to some endpoint.

```
(function($) {
    $('#what').bind('submit', function(e) {

        $.post('/url/to/send', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery **[serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** function, Like this

```
$('#what').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('#what').serialize());
  });​
```

check  on [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Kza/1/)